# Serializer is not able to find my business classes and throws HazelcastSerializationException/ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

In Memory Format - 'BINARY' works fine for storing objects in distibuted map.

```
hz:map name="mymap"  max-idle-seconds="0"  in-memory-format="BINARY"
backup-count="0" max-size="0" eviction-percentage="30" read-backup-data="true"
eviction- policy="NONE" />
```

Moment I change in-memory-format to "OBJECT". An error is thrown as:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.Customer
```

I am running a single node to start a hazelcast instance (`hz:hazelcast id="instance"`)

I have another clinet configured (hz:client id="client") to put "Customer" in map as:

```
IMap<String, Customer> objectMap = hazelcast.getMap("mymap");  
Customer customer = new Customer("gupta", 33);  
objectMap.put(key , customer);
```

with OBJECT format the above exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resove this problem I have to add "Customer" in classpath for node manager. This means node manager has to be aware of all the objects that can be added in map(s) at build phase.

Comment: +1 everywhere, as it's good description and explanation; however please try to make your titles a little more descriptive instead of just putting keywords. I've tried to help a bit with styling and the title, but feel free to edit/overwrite it as you like!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback however, I have intentionally kept title very short and exact as exception trace so that google search picks it as a header and will catch eye quickly rather then reading summary and then clicking the link.

Comment: @AmbGup - I want to make sure that I do not misunderstand - is it correct that you have Customer in both client and Server?

Comment: @user3813256 - The Customer class has to be on the java CLASSPATH for both the Client and Server.  For my case, I was using the out-of-the box Hazelcast server.sh script, so I had to edit the "export CLASSPATH=" line in that script.